# Java do while loop to for each or for loop

Tags: java, sling

I'm pretty new to Java and trying to figure out how I would convert the below code 
to a for loop or a for each loop.

```
do {
    testPages.push(testParentPage);
    if(homePage != null && testParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath())){
        isParent = true;
        break;
    }
} while((testParentPage = testParentPage.getParent()) != null);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be rewritten in a for loop like this:

```
for (; testParentPage != null; testParentPage = testParentPage.getParent()) {
    testPages.push(testParentPage);
    if(homePage != null && testParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath())){
        isParent = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thought I must admit that I don't know if it serves any benefit.

Comment: @ahubhava - your code not correct. before first iteration your changed testParentPage to testParentPage.getParent() and ignored original value for testParentPage

Comment: Remember to iterate through the parents. `testParentPage` currently stays the same throughout the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
for(; testParentPage != null; testParentpage = testParentPage.getParent()) {
    ...
}
```

The for loop structure is (variable initialization; boolean test; assignment) - usually the variable is an integer, the test is a < or >, and the assignment is an increment, but this doesn't need to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `do .. while` loop looks to be perfectly appropriate in this case. A `for` or `foreach` loop would be the tool of choice if you have a "normal" collection or something giving you an iterator. But in this case (navigating a tree structure upward) using a `for` loop would IMHO actually be confusing.

In addition to that, the condition of a `for` loop is always evaluated *before* execution of the loop body. Since you need to execute the body at least once this would make things more difficult and/or complex.

Edit: Of course it might actually make sense to perform the null-ness check at the beginning of the loop, since you call a method on `testParentPage` in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

**Re: for-each loop.**

A for each loop iterates over a Collection or array [(see docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) so you won't be able to (immediately) convert your do-while loop to a for-each loop, since you're iterating over a custom-defined hierarchy.

If you had a `List<TestPageParent>` (or whatever the type name is for that) it would work. So would `TestPageParent[]`. Or `Collection<TestPageParent>`.